# std::variant and ambiguous initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std

Consider the following code:

```
void fnc(int)
{
    std::cout << "int";
}

void fnc(long double)
{
    std::cout << "long double";
}

int main()
{
    fnc(42.3); // error
}
```

It gives an error because of an ambiguous call to `fnc`.
However, if we write the next code:

```
std::variant<int, long double> v{42.3};
std::cout << v.index();
```

the output is `1`, which demonstrates that the `double`->`long double` conversion has been chosen.
As far as I know, `std::variant` follows the C++ rules about conversion ranks, but this example shows the difference. Is there any explanation for such a behavior?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: Tried the latest versions of gcc and clang

Comment: Note that there is a condition about validity of imaginary variable definition `T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant). This cannot be used for `int` since narrowing conversion is not allowed with list-initialization. So, the `int `variant is not considered for overloading. Here is a link to the Standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#14.sentence-1.

Comment: @Daniel Langr, the same with std::variant<int, long double> v(42.3)

Comment: MSVC does not accept this initialization of the variant. I had to suffix the number with "L" to make it a `long double`: `std::variant<int, long double> v{ 42.3L };`

Comment: @Denis I referred to the list initialization of that imaginary variable `x`.

Comment: @Daniel Langr, yes, you're right, it seems very reasonable from that point

Comment: Calling with `L` works: `fnc(42.3L);` https://godbolt.org/z/74njbPnz7

Comment: [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) has a list of *defect reports* regarding conversion.  Possibly one of those covers this situation.  (If so, the compiler I'm using doesn't have the retroactive fix.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before [P0608](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html), `variant<int, long double> v{42.3}` [also has the ambiguous issue](https://godbolt.org/z/bGbjc41Mq) since `42.3` can be converted to `int` or `long double`.

P0608 changed [the behavior of `variant`'s constructors](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant#ctor-14):

> `template<class T> constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(see below);`
>
> - Let `Tj` be a type that is determined as follows: build an imaginary function `FUN(Ti)` for each alternative type `Ti` **for which `Ti x[] = {std::forward<T>(t)};` is well-formed for some invented variable `x` and,
>   if `Ti` is `cv bool`, `remove_cvref_t<T>` is bool.** The overload `FUN(Ti)`
>   selected by overload resolution for the expression
>   `FUN(std::forward<T>(t))` defines the alternative `Tj` which is the type
>   of the contained value after construction.

In your example, the `variant` has two alternative types: `int` and `long double`, so we can build the following expression

```
        int x[] = {std::forward<double>(42.3)}; // #1
long double y[] = {std::forward<double>(42.3)}; // #2
```

Since [only `#2` is well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/T1rTeWcPe), the `variant` successfully deduces the type of the contained value type `long double`.